# runtime.osx.10.10-x64.CoreCompat.System.Drawing does not show up in the output when publishing

Tags: nuget, .net-core

Why is one nuget package missing?

I have a project with nuget packages
`CoreCompat.System.Drawing`,
`runtime.osx.10.10-x64.CoreCompat.System.Drawing` and
`runtime.linux-x64.CoreCompat.System.Drawing`.

When I have done the

```
dotnet restore 
dotnet build 
dotnet publish -c release
```

sequence
both `CoreCompat.System.Drawing` and `runtime.linux-x64.CoreCompat.System.Drawing` show up in the output.

`runtime.osx.10.10-x64.CoreCompat.System.Drawing` is nowhere to be found.

Comment: Can you show your project file?

Answer (score 0):

`runtime.osx.10.10-x64.CoreCompat.System.Drawing` and `runtime.linux-x64.CoreCompat.System.Drawing` are platform-specific. From your answer, I'm guessing you are publishing on a Linux box? Did you set a `RuntimeIdentifier` in your project file, and is it set to a Linux variant? In that case, it's expected the native macOS dependencies are not included in the output.

As a sidenote, you can also replace `CoreCompat.System.Drawing` with the 'official' `System.Drawing.Common`.